# A clear step by step process for running a periodic task in a django application

Tags: django, scheduling, periodic-task

I have been trying a long for creating a periodic task in Django but there are lot of version constraints and not a clear explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This blog explains clearly

https://medium.com/@yehandjoe/celery-4-periodic-task-in-django-9f6b5a8c21c7

Thanks!!!

Comment: It would be much more useful for the readers if you'd at least mention what is the link about. It suggests to use Celery (which was already suggested in the earlier answer). For the small projects Celery is too heavy IMO.

Answer (score 7):

First of all, you want to create a management command following this guide.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/custom-management-commands/

Say we want to run the `closepoll` command in the example every 5 minutes.
You'll then need to create a script to run this command.

Linux / MacOS:

```
#!/bin/bash -e
cd path/to/your/django/project
source venv/bin/activate  # if you use venv
python manage.py closepoll  # maybe you want to >> /path/to/log so you can log the results
```

store the file as `run_closepoll.sh`, run `chmod +x run_closepoll.sh` in command line

Now we can use crontab to run our command

run `crontab -e` in your command line
add this line:
`*/5 * * * * /path/to/run_closepoll.sh`
Now the command will run every 5 minutes.
If you're not familiar with crontab, you can use this website
https://crontab-generator.org/

Windows:

```
Same content as the above example, but remove the first line and save as run_closepoll.bat
```

In your start menu, search for `Task Scheduler`, follow the instructions on the  GUI, it should be pretty simple from there.

for more info about the task scheduler, see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/taskschd/using-the-task-scheduler

Comment: Currently I'm not looking for this but sure it will help me in my project later..Thanks @rabbit.aaron

Answer (score 5):

I recommend `Celery`. What is [Celery](https://github.com/celery/celery#whats-a-task-queue)?

Celery supports scheduling tasks. Check [this doc](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [django-cron](https://github.com/Tivix/django-cron) and It works as expected. The only caveat is that you have to set a Cron job in the Linux system to run the command `python manage.py runcrons`.